# Linear programming such that feasible solution gives optimal solution to another

Tags: linear-programming

Let us say that we have a linear program $P=\{ \min C^tx \mid Ax=b,x\geq0\}$

Assume that $(P)$ has an optimal solution. Write a system of linear equations and inequalities $(P_1)$ such
that any feasible solution to $(P_1)$ gives us an optimal solution to $(P)$.

---

What I thought: I just added the complementary slackness condition along with the dual constraints to the primal constraints and solve it, as it will satisfy:

1.Primal feasibility

2.Dual feasibility

3.Complementary slackness

Hence will get the optimal solution as a feasible solution to the Linear program

but Later I noticed that if I include complementary slackness the constraints are non-linear. So any suggestion?

Comment: If you have primal and dual feasibility then complementary slackness is equivalent to the statement that primal and dual objective values are equal.

Comment: but for optimallity dont we need the complementery slackness.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370732/finding-an-optimal-solution-to-a-linear-program-among-solutions-of-another